# Android: Run App in Background

Tags: android, notifications

Greetings,

I'm trying to allow my user to close the app but still maintain a connection which listens for events. An icon should appear in the status bar and when the user clicks on the notification, they are taken back to the app.

Any ideas on how I might go about this?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to implement a service. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 9):

Use a `Service`, a `Notification`, and `startForeground()`. [Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Notifications/FakePlayer) from one of my books demonstrating this technique.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, thanks for the message. I've got the notification running, but I still need to figure out how to implement the Service and use this startForeground() method. Your code is very helpful, thanks.